# open a payment url that transfer user to browser

Tags: android, url, android-intent

i'm developing android app where forwards the user to url to complete his process, but the problem is that my application doesn't recognize the link i'm passing

here is the link

```
 www.iacademypd.com/VisaPayment.aspx?HN=  &HE=&HP=&UIDFV=34710&AP=199.000
```

and here is my android code

```
                                  Intent intent;
                                    Uri uri = Uri.parse(" www.iacademypd.com/VisaPayment.aspx?HN=  &HE=&HP=&UIDFV=34710&AP=199.000"); , uri);
                                    startActivity(intent);
```

and here is the error

```
       E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
              Process: com.example.junaida.project1, PID: 18794
              android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=www.iacademypd.com/VisaPayment.aspx?HN=  &HE=&HP=&UIDFV=34710&AP=199.000 launchParam=MultiScreenLaunchParams { mDisplayId=0 mFlags=0 } }
```

any help would be appreciated

Comment: You should first try to solve this on your own by googling it and not directly post it here as soon as you get an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
String url = "http://www.iacademypd.com/VisaPayment.aspx?HN=  &HE=&HP=&UIDFV=34710&AP=199.000";
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
i.setData(Uri.parse(url)); 
startActivity(i);
```

Comment: yea i just forgot to add http:// becuase i was getting the link from the server and it it doesn;t have that part , thank you my dear